# Boosters from set 71214 Benny don't fit

Tags: lego-dimensions

The booster pieces don't fit into their place on Benny's Dimensions set (71214). I'm talking about the bigger booster in the middle.

[image: 71214]

This seems to be a really common problem, but is there a fix?

Comment: Which of the booster pieces are you asking about? The larger ones with the translucent red cones, or the smaller ones that look like binoculars? And which connection is causing you trouble? I don't see anything wrong with the set.

Comment: From owning this, the element connecting the transred cones (a tap, https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4599#T=C) to the main body does not form a tight join (or any join, in some cases) with the positioning rocket element (https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3963#T=C). It either doesn't seat, so they fall out, or seats so tightly that it can't be removed. Seems to be a bit of variance in individual pieces though, as some work as intended.

Comment: That may be some manufacturing fault. I also have this set and inspected the pieces carefully. The rocket element has a standard Technic axle hole inside (looks like an X), and the tap piece fits in nice and snug, as it should. I also have extras of both elements, and never had a problem with them. I would call LEGO's customer service and ask for a replacement if either the rocket or the tap are faulty.

Comment: Yes it is the bigger booster. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I'm not the only one with an issue with that set, the right tap doesn't stay put, almost goes by itself...

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with several different "rocket" pieces (3963) and both variations of the "tap" piece (4599a & 4599b) despite the set listing only the "b" variant, and could not replicate the issue. There obviously had to have been a "bad" batch (or "fault" as mentioned by TheBrickBlogger) of one of the two pieces that unfortunately made it to some customers.  The simplest solution, if you don't have any extra parts of this type, would be to put a tiny piece of paper or tape on the tip of the nozzle before inserting it into the rocket piece.  Another suggestion, if you have a couple of 1x1 round plates with open studs (part #85861), is to insert these into the rocket holes to hold the nozzles in place.  There is just enough room for them:

[image]

Also, as mentioned above by TheBrickBlogger, Lego would probably be more than happy to replace any defective parts you were to encounter. Even though this is an old question I hoped maybe an answer could still be useful for someone with a similar piece problem. (In case anyone noticed, I didn't have any of that piece in blue for the nose piece)